# Почему webpack конфликтует с onclick функциями?

Tags: webpack

У меня есть большой скрипт с несколькими `onclick`-ами при запуске **webpack** он безошибочно все собирает но когда я запускаю в браузере пишет ошибку в консоли

> Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

В чем может быть проблема?
Использую стабилную версию **webpack 2.2.0.rc**

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

const config = {
    entry: "./common.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename:"bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use:"babel-loader",
                test: /\.js$/,
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Также файл **common.js** который кричит

```
const room = document.querySelector('.room-guests-count');
const form = document.querySelector('.form-open');
const adultsChildren = document.querySelector('.adults-children');
const adultsChildrenWrapper = document.querySelector('.adults-children-wrapper');

let formIsOpened = false;

room.onclick = () => { 

// он кричит на этот онклик при его удалении он 
//кричит на следиущий клик функцию и так далее пока не удалишь их все
  if(!formIsOpened) {
    form.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    form.style.display = 'none'
  }
  formIsOpened = !formIsOpened;
}

const toggleRoom = () => {

 let mainButtonPlus =  addRoomButton.onclick = () => {
    if(mainCountRoom.value == 4) return;
    mainCountRoom.value++;

    addSection();  
   }

toggleRoom();
```

Comment: С тем, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к onclick у переменной, значением которой является null. Ваш Капитан Очевидность.

Comment: @andreymal уважаемый наш капитан очевидность как тогда обяснитье почему же данная переменная работает нормально без webpack?а только кричит внутри bundler.js?Махия?

Comment: Не видя конкретного кода и конкретного способа его запуска, никто не сможет ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: хорошо покажу но только код слишком большой

Comment: Надо не большой, а [mcve]. Уменьшайте код настолько, насколько возможно, до тех пор пока проблема остаётся — и потом прикрепите его к тексту вопроса.

Comment: @andreymal вот пожалуйста

Comment: Если он кричит на `room.onclick =`, то, очевидно, переменная `room` по каким-то причинам имеет значение null. По каким — непонятно, так как **воспроизводимого** примера вы так и не предоставили. Нужны как минимум html-код и ранее упомянутый мной способ запуска данного кода.

Comment: да с html-ом все в порядке говорю же вам вне bundle.js данная функцию работает безупречно

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Cheapskate/xcseapmj/ вот что делает это функция тут и html css смотрите сколько хотите

Comment: Никто не сможет вам помочь, если вы будете заставлять народ верить вам на слово и не предоставите **самодостаточного и воспроизводимого** примера.

Comment: а где вы бандл подключаете? в конце боди? в хидере? до дива с классом room-guests-count

Comment: @Spectr вот я собрал ваш пример вебпаком с вашим `webpack.config.js` https://jsfiddle.net/90Lxo0t0/ — всё отлично работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае `JavaScript` код отрабатывает до того как выстроится `DOM`. Проверьте где Вы подключаете сгенерированый `bundle.js`

Comment: спасибо вам огромное уже 3 дня замучалсья.